# How to automatically create folders from a list in Mac OS X?

Tags: terminal, script

I have a list that looks like this in a file called `names.txt`:

```
JOHN DOE
JANE DOE
ADAM SMITH
SARAH BROWN
SUSIE JOHNSON
```

Is there a script that I can run in the Terminal that will create folders from each line in this list?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a script-writing service. We can help with a specific issue where you're stuck. Please tell us what you have done so far & what the results were.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Not sure why do you perceive the question so bad, it rather matters of a simple script of 1 LOC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an easy way to run a command for each line of a text file, and it doesn't require a script which would be overkill for a single command like `mkdir`. Use the `xargs` command like this:

```
xargs -tI % mkdir % < names.txt
```

The `-I` option tells `xargs` to run a command for each line from `STDIN`. In this case, STDIN comes from reading the `names.txt` file with `< names.txt`. The `%` character is a replacement string that `xargs` uses to as a placeholder for a line from the file. This means that everywhere `xargs` sees `%` in the command, `%` is replaced by a line from the file.

The `-t` option causes `xargs` to print each command before it's executed. It's not necessary, but it can be helpful for more complicated problems.

When `xargs` runs with the sample file, the output looks like this:

```
mkdir JOHN DOE
mkdir JANE DOE
mkdir ADAM SMITH
mkdir SARAH BROWN
mkdir SUSIE JOHNSON
```

and the `mkdir` commands make a new folder with the names from the `names.txt` file.

Comment: Very helpful answer